# How should I save alarm app data?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, plist, alarm

I am making an alarm app for the iPhone, and was wondering what would be the best way to save my data. I have tried implementing CoreData but it doesn't work. I looked and found out that to use CoreData you have to tick a checkbox that says "Use CoreData for storage" when creating a new project in Xcode, which I didn't. Instead I created a View-Based Application. Can I still implement CoreData or should I use something else like plist or SQLite.

Comment: It it is a small amount of data a plist can be fine, otherwise use CoreData.

Comment: I just want to save an alarm object for each alarm a user might create such as the fireDate, label and repeat interval. Do you think plist will be able to handle this?

Comment: Sure it's still possible to use core data. Just create a new project With the core data option checked and have a look at the project -especially the app delegate. You can copy and paste lots of the core data code into your other project

Comment: I think a plist will be ok for that

Comment: If you do go with CoreData be sure to set versioning initially.

Comment: You can always implement Core Data, even if you did not select it when first building the project. But you have to manually import the Core Data framework and add all the necessary Core Data methods and instance variables. That is why it is recommended that you just add it at the beginning. If you add a new project with Core Data, you only the AppDelegate files will change, and you can make all the adjustments there and have the app running quickly!

Comment: I think I am maybe going to go with plist, because I don't need to save that much data anyways. But if I use plist will there be any memory issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do, just store the data in NSUserDefaults as Array of Dictionaries.

For example let's say you have:

```
NSDictionary *alarmOne = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fireDateOne, labelOne, repeatIntervalOne, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fireDate", @"label", @"repeatInterval"]];
NSDictionary *alarmTwo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fireDateTwo, labelTwo, repeatIntervalTwo, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fireDate", @"label", @"repeatInterval"]];
NSArray *alarmsToBeSaved = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:alarmOne, alarmTwo, nil];
//save the alarms
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:alarmsToBeSaved forKey:@"MyAlarms"];

//get alarms back from NSUserDefaults
NSArray *alarms = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyAlarms"];
for (NSDictionary *alarm in alarms){
    NSLog(@"label of alarm: %@", [alarm objectForKey:@"label"]); //output alarm labels for example!
}
```

You could also save this Array to disk in the Documents directory of the app...

Core Data is usually better when you have large sets of data, that you want to pull out of the data base quickly (search) and better control of memory usage.

How to add a new alarm?

```
NSDictionary *alarmThree = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fireDateThree, labelThree, repeatIntervalThree, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fireDate", @"label", @"repeatInterval"]];

NSMutableArray *newAlarms = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyAlarms"]];
//add the new alarm Dict
[newAlarms addObject:alarmThree];
//save the array
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:newAlarms] forKey:@"MyAlarms"];
```

Comment: So how do I save the data the users adds?

Comment: Added how I would save a third alarm